# Lens Fungus - how to prevent it while actively using the lens in humid environment and remove it if you already have it?

Tags: lens, cleaning, maintenance, fungus, humidity

### Intro:

This is a popular question throughout this site as well as the internet in general. However the same answers which address storage are used for usage. In this question I am specifically focusing on the **active usage**. That is, how do you avoid "catching" fungus while *actively shooting in a warm humid environment*? And if you do catch it, how do you remove it preventing re-occurrence?

The two most prevalent answers involve: Silica Gel and UV/Sunlight. Both of these I would like to discard as not applicable for *active usage*, that is, when you're constantly taking the camera out of the bag and placing it back.

### Possible considerations:

#### Lens treatment

**fungicidal pellets, ammonia, borax or some other chemicals.** However their safety, usage, dosage, or combination are not clear.

#### Camera bag composition

This I haven't seen discussed much anywhere at all actually. From my personal experience, however, I can confirm that fungi are not omnivorous and do prefer certain plastics and materials. However I can't confirm composition, only that some are more susceptible than others and presumably that some are immune. Goes without saying that if you put your camera in a bag that has developed fungus there's very high likelihood of it spreading to your gear.

### Some background about my particular case

Fungus is relatively easy to "clean" with just light soap and a cloth. I even added a very light ammonia to the mix (too light perhaps?). I've done it, and it was gone for a year. However, it returned the next year (now), coinciding with the cycles of tropical environment of the country where I'm presently staying.

Initially all my 3 lenses and even the camera sensor were affected. The sensor was completely covered when I noticed the problem with the lenses. (The humidity at that particular time seemed most severe.) Although the sensor is still clean now, all 3 lenses got the fungus like a clock at the same time again. I usually pay attention to equipment, so I would estimate that it went from unnoticeable to what you see in the image I attached, in about a week or less.

**So a real solution would involve something that keeps it away, or kills it permanently, when you happen to catch it.** So if you do get it again, it comes from a different source. Clearly in my case I didn't kill it thoroughly. Taking electronic lenses apart is very hard, with a chance of damaging the fragile ribbon cables inside, so goes without saying - best minimized.

---

<sub>In this section I describe in detail why *Silica Gel and UV/Sunlight* are not applicable to this particular question. You can skip it, as long as you keep it in mind.</sub>

#### Silica Gel as a preventive measure

Silica Gel (and similar moisture absorbing chemicals) are very effective when it comes to storage of photo gear. For camera shops or people who wish to store their gear it is a perfect solution. However, in this question I address a situation where a person is actively shooting in a warm, humid environment and for such scenario silica gel is completely useless. The reason being, as you frequently open your camera bag the gel is absorbing the humidity around you rather than from the camera.

#### UV/Sunlight as a way to kill the fungus without opening the lens

No matter how long and what kind of light you shine at the fungus infected lens, fungus will not fall off. It will just stay there, degrading the image quality. No matter the duration or the type of light you use, there's no guarantee that some spores are left unexposed. And since you leave fungus remain on the lens it can not be distinguished from dead or living. So this is very risky procedure. However, I should mention, there are some people which will chose to leave the fungus on their lens in order to avoid servicing or disassembling it (or for whichever other reasons). For the sake of this question, I am  not addressing that scenario, and not considering it a solution simply because it doesn't *solve* the problem. Visually, fungus is still there. Is it alive? It's unknown. However, for storage-related questions, it is a good practice to occasionally take the lens out of storage and dry it in ventilated area exposing it to sunlight. Unless if you're in humid environment. Then it's better to just take it out of storage and swap silica gels with fresh ones.

**Caution:** *Exposure to direct sunlight has a very high chance of damaging the electronics inside the lens. Also, as the sun moves, an angle could shift causing a concentrated beam which could possibly damage something as well.*

---

**Note 1:**

- Fungus is constantly in the air around us. Yet I know many photographers who actually live in these regions and do not even use silica gells. So this would indicate that the effect of contagiousness is more important than matching the right enviromnet (humidity + warmth). So this would suggest that if you clean everything thoroughly, you should not get reoccurence. For example, my sensor is still clean, even though the lens attached to it has fungus on inside. If it were on the outside of its bottom I suppose the sensor would easily get infected at least a little bit. But the fungus most likely "activated" from within the lens.

**Note 2:**

- One more thing I've read just now, about storing lenses in ziplock bags with some silica gels. BAD idea. There's air inside the bag, and if you're in a hot environment this air can convert into condensation (moisture) which is bad for electronics inside the lens. But even aside from that, moisture is fungus's best friend.

This is one of the affected lens elements from inside my FujiFilm lens:[image: This is one of the affected lens elements from inside my FujiFilm lens]

---

#### So to recap, what is a definitive and comprehensive answer to the problem of fungus appearing on a lens while actively using it in a humid environment and how to remove it if you already have it?

Comment: That is really hard to read... Are you trying to ask 'After removing fungus, how do I prevent it from occuring again'?

Comment: @CrazyDino Well that's why I made it in bold in the first paragraph: "The question itself still stands, I would like to find a away to kill the fungus and prevent it from reoccurring."  I can change it a bit to make it more direct, what do you think?

Comment: @CrazyDino As for the possible duplicate, I mentioned about that too. I've read a lot of questions and answers here and there. This is why I made my question so specific. In this way it is different and not a duplicate. I have basically provided all the *wrong* answers making it into a "best of" or rather "worst of" compilation. Making it both informative and to filter out all answers dealing with the two I mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question, I think now it should be clear. In short, what I'm saying is, it's similar to some questions out there, but mine is much more precise as to the kind of solution I seek.

Comment: I think it still stands as a possible duplicate i'm afraid as any ways to remove/prevent fungus will be answered there rather than a new method you're hoping.

Comment: The question I'm asking is different from all the others (I've checked all I could find). I was aware of similarity before posting, so I noted that. The difference is, the people asking the other ones are too broad/generic. My question is about a particular usage. I can't put a comment to those other question saying, guys you are all wrong, and I would like to know it like this specifically... I actually started writing and it just didn't make sense as a comment, so I deleted it and done it here from scratch. It's a big and specific question, it can't be put in couple of sentences.

Comment: I couldn't make it shorter because I couldn't just say that the other approaches are wrong without thoroughly explaining why. And then I also added information from my personal experience. It's almost like a Question/Answer only I was sifting out what didn't work so far. I still need an answer as to what does work.

Comment: And just to clarify, I don't want to make a point of criticizing those who provided the answers. I mean respect that they've spent their time and effort. It's just this is one of the most misunderstood topics I've ever seen and needs to be addressed adequately with an experience-oriented approach rather than based on researched information which is predominantly incorrect. I'm not a fungi-expert, but I'll share anything I discover on the subject.

Comment: from what I have been reading it is very hard(if impossible) to get rid of fungus completely, many suggest keeping the affected equipment separately from the "healthy" one. To prevent it, you should store your body and lenses in a dry environment. I guess now all of your equipment is affected and there is not much you can do...

Comment: Ouch, it can't be that gloomy. And my camera sensor is still fungus-free. Though I've been using "infected" lenses on it. So I must've been successful that time I cleaned it. But lenses are more complex to clean of course. Drying the lenses for some time I think will just put the spores in hibernation. But if there's something... like mothballs for fungus, would be nice. I bought an anti-fungal lotion today. But it's for human skin so it has to be more tolerant. Something industrial-strength would be better, but I'll try it to see what happens.

Comment: I do think that your main focus of this question ("how do I stop/eliminate fungus once it's taken hold", if I understand you correctly), is distinct from the other questions. However, I think as written, there's entirely too much "stuff" to make it an easy to read, "Stack Exchange Good" question. For instance, your paragraph about silica gel is argumentative and entirely dismisses rechargeable desiccant options. Can you pare this down to a clear, somewhat more concise question?

Comment: @scottbb If I omit the things I've written I would get replies similar to other questions. I mean I think the question itself is a solid/precise question. And I think I could get a clear answer. I could have made it short by stating that those two things I've mentioned will not work, and omit the explanations. But wouldn't you wonder why I dismiss the two most common suggestions if I didn't mention it? So I would end up writing it anyway.

Comment: I tried to make it concise even omitted the part that silica can be dried up (in an oven) and then be able to absorb moisture again. Reason being, when you're constantly around humidity, taking camera out of the bag frequently that sachet becomes saturated before it has time to be effective. Still, if you feel there's something that can be changed I don't mind changing it.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions guys. Really appreciate the feedback. I've completely edited the question, to make it more clear and easier to understand. Call it v2.0

Comment: Out of curiosity do you store your camera/lenses inside the bag you take outside?

Comment: @CrazyDino BINGO! It should go without saying that any case/bag used in humid environments should not be used for long term storage of gear. Even if one is using a hard shelled case, such as a Pelican, the interior foam can absorb and hold moisture.

Comment: For the 3 lenses that were affected, one was inside a different container, and I haven't opened/used it at all for couple of months prior to discovering fungus. I opened it afterwards, to see how it's doing. As for the other two, I would take one with me when I would go outside, while the other would stay back, inside a (loose) pouch. I did use the same bag for the camera and whatever lens that was on it to keep it overnight. The reasoning being, humidity was just as heavy inside the room - worse in fact, due to more ventilation/sun outside. So completely drying/"safe space" isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question, as written, is that there is no solution.

You've specifically eliminated the two most effective ways for suppressing the growth of fungus: lack of dust and humidity (because they feed fungi) and UV light (because it prevents the spores from flourishing). Those are the most effective ways of preventing the fungus spores that are in the air everywhere from growing and reproducing.

Anything else requires opening up and disassembling the lens on a regular basis to clean every little part - which your question seems to exclude (It seems to me you wish to do it once and then never again). I guess if you had purely mechanical lenses you could completely immerse them in formaldehyde or something, but that might have a negative effect on the lens coatings.

Comment: Just because you or I have no answer doesn't mean there is no solution. I only eliminated the nonworking solutions. If you believe I'm wrong please correct me. I don't mind being wrong.

Comment: @Emil The answer I think is in your question. To do exactly what you want, the lens needs to be opened. Quite possibly internal components will need to be replaced or repaired using non-trivial industrial methods.

Comment: @benrudgers  As I mentioned, I have disassembled and cleaned these lenses. The fungus returned. So whatever I've done is not really a solution. A temporary fix at best. Just to give you an example of what could be done, one of the things I'm trying right now is to use anti-fungal lotion on the parts around optics as well as optics themselves (optics later cleaned). This is experimenting, however, as anti-fungal agent is probably not as strong as it could be for non-human elements.

Comment: @Michael In your post you're suggesting that I'm excluding the lens disassembly. I'm not excluding it. Please change this part as it will confuse the readers. I said that the lens *has to be disassembled anyway* to clean the fungus to avoid visually affecting images. And while you have it open, might as well use stronger methods. What those methods are -precisely- is my question. There are reports of various things that can kill fungus, such as ammonia, but they are all too broad and generic. We need a working "formulae". I can't go to a shop and say, I would like "some" ammonia.

Comment: @Emil Your 'non-working' solutions work very well for many of us who also live in hot and very humid climates. I have older lenses for old film cameras I no longer use that have developed fungus over time while being stored in the dark. Exposing them to light for a few hours per month has prevented the fungus from growing. In cases where the fungi were easy enough to get to and clean, doing so a few hours every month or two has prevented the return of fungus to places where it once was.

Comment: @MichaelClark you are misinterpreting my question. I called these solutions as non-working only in specific context. I stated above: "But for active photographers who will frequently open and close their camera bag in humid environments, it is completely useless." Then I said "For shops and people who wish to store their lenses it is of course a great solution." And (in regards to not cleaning fungus from the lens): "assuming you care enough not to just ignore it of course". Taking lenses out of storage and drying them in the sun is great. But my question is *specific* to usage not storage.

Comment: @MichaelClark I think I will split the question up into two parts. I think it's specific and all the info that's there needs to be addressed, but it seems hard for people to read the whole thing as a single unit I think.

Comment: @Emil Because fungus can feed on the materials used to bond glass elements into a single lens component, the alternatives may be to replace the lens component or use industrial techniques to debond the elements and then rebond the elements with inorganic optical bonding agents. Note that this is not cleaning. It is repair or replacement of damaged optical elements.

Comment: @Emil So the rest of us who live in very humid places don't ever open our bags and actually *use* our lenses and cameras? You're the only one, huh? Interesting. Fungus isn't likely to grow to detectable levels over a period of several hours or even several days. The key to successfully dealing with fungus isn't what one does when one is shooting, it's what one does with the gear when one is *not* shooting.

Comment: @benrudgers but these are latest FujiFilm lenses: 18-55 and 55-200, and an old Canon lens. If they couldn't come up with better materials I'm afraid it's unlikely that anyone could replace that with better alternatives. And the procedure itself... I mean I have taken all 3 of these lenses apart and cleaned them myself (due to the lack of service centers at present location) but going beyond that... Well lets just say it would hit theoretical limit of my abilities.

Comment: @MichaelClark Actually, in my situation I would estimate from visually imperceptible to what I posted in the image happened within a week's time. Two at the very most. I change lenses frequently so I would notice it. In regards to "using it", please don't get it the wrong way. I don't mean it in any demeaning way at all. I only mention it in context of distinguishing "active usage" from "storage". There is no negative or positive connotation to either. There are photographers who take out their cameras and make one shot a month - worthy of magazine cover. I'm just a humble amateur.

Comment: At any rate, I have updated the question to make it clearer and easier to read. Perhaps the original was a little confusing. Feel free to give me any feedback on it. I'm always open to suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a broad, sweeping statement - Silica Gel actually works very well...

The trick is to keep drying it out in the oven - its water adsorption is reversible.

You can get gel with an indicator - orange, it's still working; green, it's 'full'.

If you're in the field, swap it out frequently & keep checking the colours. Use sealed  lens boxes [optimally clear or frosted to allow light in, though perhaps not too much direct sunlight] & keep spare gel packs in a separate container. Use the 'overkill method'... have far more fresh gel than you will ever need.

It's dirt-cheap compared to lenses.

There's a nice & simple FAQ [here](http://www.geejaychemicals.co.uk/faq.htm)

Comment: You see, when the camera and the gear is used continuously in the humid environment, it doesn't really matter how quickly you can swap silica packs. It's a chemical, and it needs a bit of time to work. So if you keep opening and closing the bag, essentially it's trying to dehumidify the air around you.

Comment: It's not alive, it's not 'trying' to do anything... though I get your point that you are attempting to catch a waterfall in a cup. One question though - do you live in a rainforest? [I'm going to actually have to ask that as a question on here... how humid does humid have to be; & does it have to be combined with heat? Manchester vs Delhi...

Comment: Well, now, saying that it's not even trying... but alright I guess it's a chemical so it has no feelings ;) I haven't been to Manchester so can't compare. The region where it first occurred is near Kolkata. I've been to some extremely hot places but very dry, the problem didn't occur.  Before this, I've stayed in humid but cool place - nothing. It occurred first time last year, exactly the same time as now. Coinciding with monsoon season. So it definitely needs Humidity + Heat (~35+C). But I know others who live here and they don't have it. So source from where it can spread matters more.

Comment: Fungi are alive. They are biological organisms that use organic compounds to reproduce and grow. They produce organic compounds as waste that are byproducts of their biological process. Their spores are similar to the seeds of plants - they can remain dormant for a long time but when the conditions are favorable they will become active and grow.

Comment: My comment was referring to the Silica Gel...

Answer (score 0):

**Store your camera gear when not in use in (dried/uncooked) rice and take it out for as short a periods as possible**

Ok this may sound weird.. there's the whole idea of if you drop your phone in the sink (or in reality toilet) people are told to put their phone in rice and leave it. I thought hmm maybe this might work for you so thought I'd do some research on if this method works for phones to begin with.

Well. You're in luck. The origin of this story/method dates back from 1946.. in [Popular Photography magazine](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jmczAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA178&dq=rice+desiccant+camera+equipment&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rice&f=false) and was about storing camera gear in rice to protected the gear from fungus in the humidity as an alternative to silica gel. It's quite a long article but does talk about equipment in the tropics.

Comment: Yes, but my question is specifically "how to prevent it while actively using the lens in humid environment" For storage it's a different story, and there are many useful techniques, involving silica gel etc. As for using rice, I heard of this before with cell phones. Interesting to know how it works. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Emil honestly. I don't think you're going to be able to. Your best bet is prevention where you can.

Comment: Well, I won't give up just yet. What I known so far is that there are chemicals that kill/repel fungi. There are materials that encourage or discourage its growth. To put this into a practical and working solution might not be so obvious/straightforward, but is certainly doable, though some experimentation may be in order.